# Using Powershell to login to a url and download a file

Tags: powershell, url, download

I am having difficulty creating a Powershell script to login to a website and download a file.  The script seems to be logging in just fine (I receive a successful status return) but when I attempt to download the file, I receive an Unauthorized message in return.

Code is below:

```
$r=Invoke-WebRequest http://testurl/index.htm -SessionVariable fb
$form = $r.Forms[0]
$form.fields["loginusername"] = "user"
$form.fields["loginpassword"] = "pass"
$r=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://testurl/index.htm" + $form.Action) -WebSession $fb -Method POST -Body $form.Fields
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://testurl/api/table.csv" -WebSession $fb -OutFile "C:\status\current.csv"
```

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the example you're trying to reference.  It had a few mistakes when I tried to replicate it, too.  I've automated some site logins/downloads; here's an adjustment to try:

```
$r=Invoke-WebRequest http://testurl/index.htm
$r.Forms.fields.loginusername = 'user'
$r.Forms.fields.loginpassword = 'pass'

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://testurl' + $form.Action) -SessionVariable fb -Method POST -Body $r
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://testurl/api/table.csv' -WebSession $fb -OutFile 'C:\status\current.csv'
```

Comment: Thanks.  But still receiving an "Invoke-WebRequest : Unauthorized" on the file request.

Comment: @Vick Do you know what unauthorized means?  You don't have permissions to access the content you're attempting to.

Comment: No.  I have permissions.  If I were to open a browser and put "https://testurl/api/table.csv" into the url, I will receive and Unauthorized message.  If I login to testurl first and then put in "https://testurl/api/table.csv" the file will download.

Comment: Are you doing any validation that your session is valid and authentication was successful?  On the login attempt, store the output into a variable and look at the innerHTML to see if you get a message about incorrect credentials (assuming the login tells you as much) @Vick

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like the form is not logging in at all.  I'll revisit and try again.

Comment: If there's a specific login page such as `url/login.htm`, I'd suggest utilizing that over an index landing page @Vick

Comment: Sorry if this is a noob question, but how can you convert this powershell to batch? I tried to do it powershell -Command "" but it says it can't set a variable or something

Comment: @CreativiTimothy You can just separate each command with a semicolon and concatenate them into the quotes.